# How to declare a lot a document.getElementById variables at the same time

Tags: javascript, dom

I declared some variables:

```
var availableTile1 = document.getElementById("c1");

var availableTile2 = document.getElementById("c2");

var availableTile3 = document.getElementById("c3");

var availableTile4 = document.getElementById("c4");

var availableTile5 = document.getElementById("c5");

var availableTile6 = document.getElementById("c6");
```

As you see, only the number is different. Is there a quicker and clearer way of defining all variables at once?

**Note:** I heard about "destructuring assignment", but I couldn't apply it with document.getElementById.6
Thank you for your answers.

EDIT: 
`availableTile.style.border = "none";
     availableTile.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";`

This works if  availableTile is an Id, but somehow not if it is a class?!

Comment: Just add a common class and get the collection by class selector

Comment: give them a class and use `document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: yes, but for some reason (I really don't know why), when I use classes my code doesn't work (see edit)

Comment: @SteelCode94 But you know that `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection` rather than a single element and that you can use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) to read any errors, right?

Comment: yes... the console returns that the element is not defined.

Comment: @Xufox because I want each availableTile element to be a single element (so using an Id) but I have a lot (around 100) of them to declare...

Comment: @SteelCode94 Then you have to learn how to work with `document.getElementsByClassName` and `HTMLCollection`s. See the linked post for several ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use variables. Do use an array. Populate it in a loop.

```
var available_tiles = [];
for (var i = 1; i <=6; i++) {
    available_tiles.push( document.getElementById("c" + i) );
}
```

You could get a similar result by changing the HTML to make every element a member of the same class. You can then get an array-like object with

```
var available_tiles = document.getElementsByClassName("tile");
```

or

```
var available_tiles = document.querySelectorAll(".tile");
```

Comment: If using IDs instead of classes, this could be written functionally: `availableTiles = Array.from({length: 6}, (_, i) => document.getElementById("c" + (i + 1)));`.